# Is There A List Of Error Codes MVC May Throw?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I  need to catch error codes in an mvc app. Is there a list of error codes mvc throws? Are the the same as the basic HttpCodes? For example if the [Authorized] attribute fails on a class is a 401 error code thrown or is it something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exceptions thrown by MVC are the largely (entirely?) the same as regular .Net exceptions.

The error codes returned to the server - which are then forwarded on to the browser - are the same range of HTTP codes as any other web server.